# When using setString it doesn't store the variable

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to set a string to receive a value from other elements. I'm currently using selenium java. I don't understand why I get NullPointerException.

The method used for setString is that,

```
  public void setString(String name, String value) {
    this.configuration.setString(name, value);
  }
```

Basically, this method set using HashMaps.
But when I use debug mode on IntelliJ

```
element(EXAMPLE_1).getText()
```

I get that:

[image]

That's the string that I want to save.
But when I do :

```
setString(VAR_EXAMPLE, Selenium.getInstance().getCurrentDriver()
            .findElements(By.xpath(EXAMPLE_1)).getText())
```

I get this error

[image]

Can anyone help me out? Really appreciate :)

Comment: I'd break it down into two lines there...  something's null... hard to say without seeing more code, but I'd suspect Selenium.getInstance() right off the bat.  Why so many method calls just to get at the driver?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with findElement instead of findElements, get Text is only applicable on particular element not on all elements

```
.findElement(By.xpath(EXAMPLE_1)).getText())
```

Comment: still the same error :/

Comment: add wait condition before get text. if element is not loaded, you will see this error.

Comment: don't think wait solve the problem because I used debugger mode.